# Is there a way to pin a folder in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a solution that deep down in the belly of the TFS folder hierarchy beast.  6 subfolders down.  So as you can imagine, it's pain to go and locate it every time I open Visual Studio.

Is there a way to pin the folder somewhere or tell TFS to auto open to that directory whenever I open Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a direct link to a folder in Source Control Explorer with the [Favorite Documents](http://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) extension (developed by me).

Answer (score 0):

from VS have you looked in: File > Recent Projects and Solutions?

Comment: Yeah, but a good chunk of the time I am looking for a support file (like .sql or something) that I need in there.  That's why I am wanting to pin or a shortcut the folder.